# How to return multiple variables with different capitalization combinations | PHP

Tags: php, function, capitalization

Ok, I will try to make this as simple as possible.

I have a script that searches a file for a variable `$search`.
The variable `$search` is the first two letters of a user input, `$user`.

What I would like to do is to find out what the capitalization of the two letters of `$search` are, then to generate several more variables from that information.

The basic layout idea is this:

```
$cap1 = /*the capitalization of $search[0]*/;
$cap2 = /*the capitalization of $search[1]*/;

if (/*capitalization of $cap1 is UPPERCASE*/){
    $uncap1 = /*LOWERCASE capitalization of $cap1*/;
} else if (/*capitalization of $cap1 is LOWERCASE*/){
    $uncap1 = /*LOWERCASE capitalization of $cap1*/;
}

if (/*capitalization of $cap2 is UPPERCASE*/){
    $uncap2 = /*LOWERCASE capitalization of $cap2*/;
} else if (/*capitalization of $cap2 is LOWERCASE*/){
    $uncap2 = /*LOWERCASE capitalization of $cap2*/;
}

echo "Original phrase:" . $search . "\n";
echo "New phrase:" . $uncap1 . $uncap2 . "\n";
```

I would like to know how to reverse capitalization. (I would also like to know if the multi-ine comments can be used in the middle of a line)

I was considering to just use a str_replace function, but I'm too lazy to type the alphabet 4 times.

Any help would be much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using some string functions, what you appear to need can be achieved.  I try to stay away from regular expression whenever possible since string functions alone (generally) are more efficient.  In this particular case I use `str_split()` to convert the string to an array and `strtr()` (string translate) to convert the cases.  Setting up two variables `$lcase` and `$ucase` with copies of the 26-letter alphabet are used for the translations.

The following function should do what you need, which from the sound of your question is that you want to reverse the case of a string.  Note that this will work on strings of more than two characters also.

```
function translateCase($str)
{
    $lcase = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    $ucase = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $rebuilt = "";
    foreach(str_split($str) as $char) {
        if(strstr($lcase, $char)) {
            $rebuilt .= strtr($char, $lcase, $ucase);
        } else {
            $rebuilt .= strtr($char, $ucase, $lcase);
        }
    }
    return $rebuilt;
}
```

Using the function with examples...

```
var_dump(translateCase("AA"));
var_dump(translateCase("bb"));
var_dump(translateCase("Jw"));
var_dump(translateCase("rV"));
```

...will produce the following results:

```
string(2) "aa"
string(2) "BB"
string(2) "jW"
string(2) "Rv"
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: **But:** I am seeing a lot of `NULL`s. Help!

Comment: Hmmm... I replaced `var_dump` with `echo` and the `NULL`s disappeared. I wonder why?

Comment: @AlfredPersonMc That is odd, using `echo` or `var_dump()` produced similar string results for me.